# Understanding Inbound/Outbound connectiona in Azure VM

Tags: azure, active-directory, server, outbound, inbound

I have a problem identifying what counts as inboud & outbound connections to determine whether Azure VM is good for our SMB or not.

the scenario we have is as follows:
I would like to get an Azure VM to host win server, it should include File Sharing which has different set privileges to the users, the server is a DC as it'll contain active directory.

i get that uploading any data to the VM, like adding files to attached VHD, or creating/updating files to shared folders is considered inbound and its free.
but what counts as outbound? would downloading or accessing files on shared folders counts as outbound?

i have basic knowledge when t comes to servers & azure so bear with me please, and if you guys have any suggestions to enhance the given scenario please share :)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Outbound traffic is all data leaving the Azure data center, with data centers within the same Azure region being the exception.

In your case, if your SMB clients exists outside of Azure or in a different region within Azure, you will be billed for traffic clients receives, e.g. browsing and downloading files.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Bink! actually Azure VM will be in East Europe while everyone, including the system administrator is in the middle east. does that mean we will be billed for almost everything?